# Getting a percentage discount

Tags: finance, percentages

I'm currently working on a website which has a list of products with predefined prices.

The owner of the website would like me to add two membership levels.

- Membership Level A will see a 15% increase in prices.
- Membership Level B will see the current defined prices with no increase.

Since it's easier to offer discounts rather than markups, I decided to take a route where I would increase all prices by 15% and offer a discount to Membership Level B.

However, what that discount would be to get the current prices is a mystery.

```
$A + 15% = $B
```

But

```
$B - 15% ≠ $A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following formula

```
% decrease = -100 * ( (B - A) / |A| )

A = Initial Number
B = Final Number
```

If Product is prices at `$100`, an increase of `15%` would make it `$115`. But decrease `15%` from `$115` would get you `$97.75`.

Using an online calculator gives me a value of `13.04348%` decrease.

Comment: This should be incorporated into the question body.